Approximate 2D noisy point cloud with area-constrained closed B-splines
Use a closed cubic B-spline to approximate noisy 2D data points that are nearly circularly distributed. The area enclosed by the reconstructed B-spline should be constrained to remain constant.
How to achieve this approximation using MATLAB or Python? How to impose the constraint to the reconstructed B-spline and make the area a constant? A trivial question: if the areas enclosed by control point polygons are the same, can we derive that the areas enclosed by their corresponding B-splines are the same as well? Any ideas or available source codes? Thank you so much!
The desired outcome of the codes. The black crosses are the known noisy data points; the red lines indicate the estimated control point polygon; the light blue curve is the estimated b-spline curve. The area within the estimated b-spline curve should be a constant.

